# Problem with interruptions in Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino, interrupt

I work with interruptions in Arduino UNO. In this project, I want to when the Door is opened the LED blink 10 times, and when the door is closed again, stop blinking the LED and exit the function. But in this code the LED only turn on and off once and it does not flash again.
My other problem is that, when the door is opened or closed, sometimes the opened or closed word appears several times in the Series monitor.

```
const byte LED_Red = 13;
const byte DOOR_SENSOR = 2; // magnetic door sensor pin

volatile int SensorState = LOW; // 0 close - 1 open wwitch

void setup()
{
Serial.begin(9600);
pinMode(LED_Red, OUTPUT);
pinMode(DOOR_SENSOR, INPUT_PULLUP);
attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(DOOR_SENSOR), DoAction, CHANGE);
}

void DoAction()
{
    SensorState = digitalRead(DOOR_SENSOR);
    if (SensorState == HIGH) {
    Serial.println("Opened");
    blinkLED(10, 500);
}
    else {
    Serial.println("Closed");
        }
}

void blinkLED(int repeats, int time)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < repeats; i++) {
        if (SensorState == HIGH) {
        digitalWrite(LED_Red, HIGH);
        delay(time);
        digitalWrite(LED_Red, LOW);
        delay(time);
    }
    else
        return;
}
}

void loop()
{
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't simply put a `delay()` on an interrupt's function. You need to just set a flag when the door is opened and based on that start `blinkLED` inside the main loop.

I also recommend you to use `millis()` function for an unblocking delay inside `blinkLED` function (e.g when you want to stop blinking while the door is closed).

```
const byte LED_Red = 13;
const byte DOOR_SENSOR = 2; // magnetic door sensor pin

// flag to check door is opened
volatile bool isOpened = false;

//flag to check already blinked
volatile bool isBlinked = false;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(LED_Red, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(DOOR_SENSOR, INPUT_PULLUP);
    attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(DOOR_SENSOR), DoAction, CHANGE);
}

void DoAction()
{
    if (digitalRead(DOOR_SENSOR) == HIGH)
    {
        //Serial.println("Opened");
        isOpened = true;
    }
    else
    {
        isOpened = false;
        isBlinked = false;
        //Serial.println("Closed");
    }
}

void blinkLED(int repeats, int time)
{
    byte LEDState = LOW;
    unsigned long delay_start = millis();
    for (int i = 0; i < 2 * repeats; i++)
    {
        //Toggle LED state
        if (LEDState == HIGH)
            LEDState = LOW;
        else
            LEDState = HIGH;
        // set value
        digitalWrite(LED_Red, LEDState);
        // some unblocking delay
        while (millis() - delay_start < time)
        {
            // return if door is closed
            if (!isOpened)
            {
                // turn off LED
                digitalWrite(LED_Red, LOW);
                return;
            }
        }
        delay_start = millis();
    }
    isBlinked = true;
}

void loop()
{
    // Check isBlinked beacue don't want to blink again until door is closed
    if (isOpened && !isBlinked)
    {
        blinkLED(10, 500);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would further suggest **not** putting print statements in your ISR. From the Arduino documentation: "*Generally, an ISR should be as short and fast as possible*". print statements are generally very "expensive" in terms of time. You can read more here: [Arduino Docs - AttachInterrupt](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/external-interrupts/attachinterrupt/)

Comment: @GMc Thanks I edited the code and commented out those lines.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answers
The code worked fine and I extend the program by adding a new interrupt. Now I want to know if it's possible to get rid of the Loop function. I think that it's not a good idea that we continually check the variables in the Loop to if the values has changed or not. Is not it better to write the program so that only when there is an interruption in the program, the value of these variables is checked?
Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: @hamidmousavi Yes, you can call `blinkLED` in your interrupt routine but the problem is `millis()` won't progress so you won't able to use delay. You can find more about that in [here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/22212/using-millis-and-micros-inside-an-interrupt-routine). Also it is not a bad idea to check flags inside `loop` function.